# Running nUnit tests in a multithreaded fashion

Tags: .net, multithreading, unit-testing, nunit

Is it possible to run nunit tests in a multithreaded fashion? Is there any runner which can provide this?

Before someone jump on "unit test" concept, let me explain: These are **not unit tests** we are using nunit for functional / integration testing as well, and some of those tests are incredibly slow, got lots of wait state. Therefore multithreading can help them massively.

I know as a last resort I can roll my own multi-threading within the tests but that'll introduce an unrequired overhead.

Comment: +1 for explaining the scenario :)

Comment: as an experienced stackoverflower I know what's going to happen when you ask something like this :D

Answer (score 2):

Try [Pnunit](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=pnunit&r=2.5)

Answer (score 2):

But ofcourse we do have to have TeamCity support for this too ;-)

Allegedly NUnit3 will have multithreading support.

Answer (score 1):

here is a reference to PNUint http://www.codicesoftware.com/opdownloads2/oppnunit.aspx. We use it as a part of the environment to load test a web app with extensive ajax functionality

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at the Overshore multithreaded test framework which has a ThreadManager class you could always extend slightly to add the concept of 'failed' tests.

http://weblogs.asp.net/rosherove/archive/2007/06/22/multi-threaded-unit-tests-with-osherove-threadtester.aspx

If you're only using asserts, you can count the exceptions.

Good luck

ps: why not run several nant/nunit-runner out of process?

Comment: yeah I've seen that, but that code is not any different than just running threads in your own thread pool (or am I missing something). It's not something clever such as [ThreadTest] - now that'd be cool :)

Actually running multiple instances of nUnit is not a bad idea, just a little bit messy and requires quite a bit manual labour.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on a .NET port of the [MultithreadedTC Java library](http://www.cs.umd.edu/projects/PL/multithreadedtc/overview.html). My port is called [Ticking Test](https://github.com/donkirkby/donkirkby/tree/master/TickingTest), and the source code is published on GitHub.

TickingTest wasn't originally intended to do what you're attempting, but it might work. It lets you write a test class with several methods marked with a TestThread attribute. Each thread can wait for a certain tick count to arrive, or assert what it thinks the current tick count should be. When all current threads are blocked, a coordinator thread advances the tick count and wakes up any threads that are waiting for the next tick count. If you're interested, check out the [MultithreadedTC overview](http://www.cs.umd.edu/projects/PL/multithreadedtc/overview.html) for examples. MultithreadedTC was written by some of the same people that wrote [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/).

I've used my port successfully on a small project. The major missing feature is that I have no way to track newly created threads during the test.

Answer (score 0):

I can't believe MSTest isn't listed. Visual Studio has been supporting multiple concurrent tests for ages.

Comment: MSTest the unit testing tool?  I think you may be referring the the Performance Load test tools which are only available in Visual Studio Ultimate edition.  NUnit has tested concurrent tests for a while but the author is looking to do integration tests and need more than just a simple test runner.

Answer (score 0):

We set up a recursive MSBuild script to run the unit test dlls concurrently, which looks something like this:

```
  <Target Name="UnitTestDll">
    <Message Text="Testing $(NUnitFile)" />
    <ItemGroup>
      <ThisDll Include="$(NUnitFile)"/>
    </ItemGroup>
    <NUnit ToolPath="$(NUnitFolder)" Assemblies="@(ThisDll)" OutputXmlFile="$(TestResultsDir)\%(ThisDll.FileName)-test-results.xml" ExcludeCategory="Integration,IntegrationTest,IntegrationsTest,IntegrationTests,IntegrationsTests,Integration Test,Integration Tests,Integrations Tests,Approval Tests" ContinueOnError="true" />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="UnitTest" DependsOnTargets="Clean;CompileAndPackage">
      <Message Text="Run all tests in Solution $(SolutionFileName)" />
      <CreateItem Include="$(SolutionFolder)**\bin\$(configuration)\**\*.Tests.dll" Exclude="$(SolutionFolder)\NuGet**;$(SolutionFolder)**\obj\**\*.Tests.dll;$(SolutionFolder)**\pnunit.tests.dll">
        <Output TaskParameter="Include" ItemName="NUnitFiles" />
      </CreateItem>
    <ItemGroup>
      <TempProjects Include="$(MSBuildProjectFile)">
        <Properties>NUnitFile=%(NUnitFiles.Identity)</Properties>
      </TempProjects>
    </ItemGroup>
    <RemoveDir Directories="$(TestResultsDir)" Condition = "Exists('$(TestResultsDir)')"/>
    <MakeDir Directories="$(TestResultsDir)"/>

    <MSBuild Projects="@(TempProjects)" BuildInParallel="true" Targets="UnitTestDll" />
  </Target>
```

You obviously still need your Compile targets (or in our case CompileAndPackage) to actually build the test dlls first.

This also messes up your NUnit results for most reporting tools but having hit that problem already we wrote a tool to help with that: https://github.com/15below/NUnitMerger